# Is there an equivalent of a bootstrap.php for python?

Tags: python

In php, people often call a bootstrap file to set variables used throughout a program. I have a python program that calls methods from different modules. I want those methods from different modules to share some variables. Can I set these variables up in something like a boostrap.py? Or is this not very "pythonic" because a module should contain all of the variables it needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to create something called a `settings.py` file, that houses are your shared variables of importance.

This approach is followed by the django team for their web framework called django, whcih creates a `settings.py` file to house all the data that needs to be shared, for example database logins, and static file roots.